# Expectation value of standard deviation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

I was trying to calculate the expectation value of the standard deviation, if I only take two data points into account. My code is the following:

```
n[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x];
σ2[x1_, x2_] = 
  FullSimplify[
   Sqrt[1/2*((x1 - (x1 + x2)/2)^2 + (x2 - (x1 + x2)/2)^2)]];
E2[x1_, x2_] = σ2[x1, x2]*n[x1]*n[x2]
Assuming[{σ > 0, μ > 0}, 
 Integrate[
  E2[x1, x2], {x1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x2, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

The results I get are:

$$\frac{\sqrt{(\text{x1}-\text{x2})^2} e^{-\frac{(\text{x1}-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}-\frac{(\text{x2}-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{4 \pi  \sigma ^2}$$
$$0$$

Where the first line is the function I integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ in two dimension. The result $0$ can  not be true since both parts, the exponential and the root are non-negative functions and clearly give a positive value for almost all possible values.

I must have made some mistake at some point, but I do not know where...

Thanks in advance,
Glostas

Comment: A manual derivation for me yields `(σ/(2 Sqrt[2]π)) Integrate[Exp[-x1^2/2 - x2^2/2]Piecewise[{{x2 - x1, x2 > x1}}, x1 - x2], {x1, -∞, ∞}, {x2, -∞, ∞}]`. However, `Assuming[{x1, x2, μ} ∈ Reals && σ > 0, Expectation[StandardDeviation[{x1, x2}], {x1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ]}]]` yields 0. Hmm...

Comment: `Assuming[σ > 0 && μ > 0 && {x1, x2} ∈ Reals, Integrate[FullSimplify[E2[x1, x2]], {x1,-∞, ∞}, {x2,-∞,∞}]]` gives 
`σ/Sqrt[π] `

Comment: @rhermans This works perfect, thanks. I still fo not really understand he problem with my original function

Comment: I don't understand it either, that is why I didn't leave it as an answer. I would not discard a BUG.